# Calling a method of a randomly generated subclass from its superclass

Tags: java, oop

I have the following totally abstract scenario which I am trying to put together using OOP concepts, but I'm struggling with how to do it right.

I have 3 types of cars. There's only 2 things this car can do - drive (for 1 km) and stop. All cars can be driven and stopped in the same way. So in the OOP world, I'd represent it as something like so:

```
class Car{
    drive(){...}
    stop(){...}
}
```

The three types of cars are CarA, CarB and CarC, which are all subclasses of this parent class Car. So let's take one of them, say CarA, which would look something like:

```
class CarA extends Car{}
```

So far, so good. Now here's my task. I have a large number of cars of different types inside an array of type Car (this is possible since the class Car is a parent of all types of cars). I have a function that picks out a random car (using a randomly generated integer within a range that functions as the index), called getRandomCar()). Once I get a random car, my job is to drive the car (which happens for 1 km as per the function defined inside the Car parent class) and then stop the car. So I do something like:

```
Car car = (Car) getRandomCar(cars); //cars is the Car array with all the different cars
car.drive(); //car is driven for 1 km
car.stop(); //car is stopped.
```

This works because the random car that I get is always type-casted to its parent class before storing it into a Car reference variable called car. When I call car.drive(), it calls the Car class' method called drive().

Now suppose one of these cars, say CarA, has a slightly different way of driving. So inside my class definition for CarA, I'll overload the method drive().

Now my question is, in the above scenario, if one of the random cars that I get is of type CarA, then car.drive() calls the parent method and not the child method. But the way to drive the CarA is different from other cars, and that's the reason why it has an overloaded method.

So in this case, is there a good way to easily call CarA's own method other than specifically putting an if condition before calling car.drive() and checking if the random car's type is that of CarA (this could be a tedious process, if say all cars have their own drive method). Is there a good and elegant implementation of such a scenario in the OOP universe?

Comment: You got it wrong, it's the overloaded `drive` method from `CarA` that will be called even if the declared type of your variable is just `Car`. However, `CarA` can call the method from `Car` by using `super.drive()` if needed

Comment: Read about `Dynamic Method Dispatch or Runtime Polymorphism in Java`. You're wrong in claiming *... if one of the random cars that I get is of type CarA, then car.drive() calls the parent method and not the child method....*.

Comment: So even if the reference variable is of a parent class type, its the overloaded method in the child class that is called in Java?

Comment: @ArvindSasikumar Exactly. If it did not, it would make overloading completly useless. Also, it's not just in Java but all OOP languages

Comment: This scenario is one of the major points of OOP universe. Your cast (`Car car = (Car) getRandomCar(cars)`) is not useful: `CarA` does not need to be cast to `Car` because it already IS a `Car`.  Your statement `then car.drive() calls the parent method` is not true. The most derived method is called, in your case that of `CarA`. To clarify your thinking, try making `Car` into an interface, then implement `DefaultCar` and then derive CarA, B and C.

Comment: Thank you, that clears my query.

Comment: @ArvindSasikumar This confusion about Java polymorphism is common for C++ programmers coming to Java. If you're one such, in Java `virtual` is default. The closest thing to non-virtual methods in C++ is `final` method, but that's not same either.

Comment: As a follow up, what would I do if I had to call the parent method instead explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, methods are checked at compile-time, but bound at run-time. When you declare your `car` variable as

```
Car car = (Car) getRandomCar(cars);
```

`car` is now an instance of `CarA` with a reference type of `Car`. As far as the compiler can tell, `car` is a `Car`.

When you call `car.drive()` the compiler checks that method against the definition of the `Car` class. `Car` does indeed contain a method named called `drive()`, so the compilation succeeds. When the program is actually run, the JVM reaches that statement and calls `drive()` **on the actual object**. Since `car` is actually a `CarA`, `CarA`'s version of `drive()` is called. For `CarB` and `CarC`, which don't include their own definition, `Car`'s version of `drive()` is automatically inherited.

---

Some other notes (things I noticed and things that were mentioned in comments):

1. The scenario you're describing here is called **overriding**, not overloading. Overloading is making multiple methods with the same name and return type, but different parameters. Overriding is replacing the functionality of a superclass by making an identical method in the subclass.
2. In your `car` assignment, you don't need to cast to a `Car`. Since `getRandomCar()` can return any type of `Car`, it must be that it's return type is `Car`. `car` is also declared with the type of `Car`, so there's no casting necessary.